# Why would python37 stop downloading a url?

Tags: python, download, file-conversion

This program was working for years. I didn't use it for several months, and now it won't download the necessary files. I'm using python37 on Windows 7.
There also is a new problem with decoding bytes to string.

Here's the relevant subroutine, with annotations:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import socket
import sys, os
# ---
def geturl(url, stk):   # reads a web page into a string
    print("at180: into geturl with url=",url)

#Here's the url I passed it
#https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/qqq/history?period1=1480204800&period2=1637971200&interval=1mo&filter=history&frequency=1mo

# it returns a 404 error, but works fine if pasted into Chrome browser, or when used in a perl call to get. 

# I tried a simpler one: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/QQQ/history?p=QQQ
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/QQQ/history?p=QQQ" 
# it also returned a 404 error

#I tried one even simpler
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com" 
# this one does not return a 404 error but has conversion error from byte to str

    try:
        junk = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=4).read()
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print("URLError with ",stk," = ", e) 
        return("Error")
    except socket.timeout as e:
        return("Timeout")
    page = str( junk, encoding='utf8' ) # convert from type 'bytes' to type 'str

# error here with the simple url: 
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte "

    print("\nat197, returning page")
    pause()
    return(page)
```

Why can't the urllib.request.urlopen find a url which works fine if passed to the Chrome browser?

Why does it find it if I leave off everything but the basic url address?

How can I print out the byte string 'junk' so I can read it?
It seems to have many nonHex characters.

Do web pages no longer use UTF-8? If so, what encoding should I specify?

Comment: Have you tried using the requests lib? (just to see if you can get something with it from that url)

Comment: Chances are, finance.yahoo.com is now blocking python requests based on the user agent.

Comment: If you have further issues, feel free to respond below - if you feel your question is answered, you can accept the answer with the checkmark next to it and it will show as answered on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with Python changing, but it appears the page used to serve you something that wasn't gzipped and it is now.

Here's an example that works without external libraries like `requests`:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
from io import BytesIO
import gzip

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com"
try:
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    if response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
        buf = BytesIO(response.read())
        with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf) as f:
            content = f.read()
    else:
        content = response.read()
    page = content.decode()
    print(page)
except (urllib.error.URLError) as e:
    print("URLError with ",url," = ", e)
```

I've also replaced your `str()` cast with an `str.decode()` (and since it's UTF-8, default is OK).

You indicated that you were still getting 404 on pages like https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/QQQ/history?p=QQQ. That's correct and again the result of something changing on the Yahoo site. Yahoo doesn't like you scraping their pages (and their terms probably say you shouldn't). So it checks if it's a script making the request or a regular browser.

You can make Python lie about it:

```
    request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36')
```

If you add that, the request will work. That is, until Yahoo tightens the rules some more and makes you make more changes.

This is why it's generally not a good idea to base an application that you need to work for longer off of scraping front end pages. Instead, base a script on a supported API (which probably means getting an API key and possibly paying a fee, if you hit it a lot).

Comment: I don't think it's a Yahoo problem, because I have no problem scraping those pages in Perl, with LWP::Simple get. And I've been doing that for years, with nary a peep from Yahoo. And I don't think it's returning a zipped file, since it just says it can't find the file I'm looking for.  But thanks for the suggestion to use decode. I never ran across that before. Also, I used to use the Yahoo API, but they discontinued it a few years back. And I think they expect people to just scrape the page, because, when it works, they serve a big JSON file, not html.

Comment: You're discounting the fact that Perl may have been capable of dealing with gzipped content all along and spoofing an agent header as well (which is common practice, to the frustration of those against scraping). The fact that you say your code used to work makes it next to certain that Yahoo did indeed change its practices - which would make sense, almost every serious business does. I'd bet money on it. If you must prove it to yourself to believe it, you can always just download whatever version of Python you used to use and try - Python supports having multiple installations side by side.